# Jetpack Compose View.draw IllegalArugmentExceptions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

After migrating a large percentage of an application to jetpack compose, I am seeing a high amount of vague `View.draw` crashes on multiple devices, which are typically low-end.

The crashes are mostly IllegalArgumentExceptions from `androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt)`

I understand that I am failing one of the `require()` checks in the delegate class but the stack traces are very unhelpful. I am not even sure which screens these crashes are happening on.I am using fragments to hold the composables.

I am pretty sure it is one of these checks failing:
`require(root.isAttatched)`
`require(root.isPlaced)`
`require(!duringMeasureLayout)`

I am unsure of a solution, and I haven't been able to find any leads by searching.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
    androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:567)
    androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:774)
    androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:216)
    androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:999)
    android.view.View.draw(View.java:23901)
    android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22767)
    android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5339)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5311)
    android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22714)
    android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5339)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5311)
```

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: No, but the numbers appear to be going down with every compose library update.